# Creating a Community User via Apex from a Contact

Tags: apex, community, customer-community, user-management

We are rolling out a community for our customer base and I am attempting to create an Batch Class to create and activate OR deactivate Community Users based on when they have been deemed to be active by a Designated user from their organization.  Our Account-Customer structure is not standard - Most of our Contacts do not role up to an Account.

I am running into an issue when attempting to insert my new Users because I don't have specific fields related to Role populated.  When we create an External User via the Salesforce UI, the role is automatically created as " Customer User".  However, when I am creating them through the Apex Batch, I don't do so.

Must I create the UserRole for the Account prior to inserting the User?  Is there something that I am missing where Salesforce should do this on my behalf?

Two things would be helpful to me:

1. A list of the minimum fields that must be present to create a new Community User from a Contact that has an Account.
2. a Blog post or Salesforce Documentation that outlines what happens on the backend when creating a Community User.

Or is there a really easy built in Class/Method that I am unaware of that would solve this problem for me and make me feel really dumb for not having found it yet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're looking in the wrong spot. The role that needs to exist is on the owner of the account record, not directly on the community user.

We have a workflow that forces all of our contacts/accounts to have the same user act as the owner and gave that owner a very generic role which allows us to easily create community users via apex.

I can understand that won't work for everyone...

**Make sure the Account's Owner has a role:**

```
if (contact.Account.Owner.Role != null) {
    // Do your thang
}
```

**Minimum Fields:**

We have the following fields defined in our JIT handler:

```
            u.firstName = '';
            u.lastName = '';
            u.ContactId = contactLookup[0].Id;
            u.Username = 'username';
            u.Email = 'email';
            u.CommunityNickname = 'nickname';
            u.Alias = '';
            u.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Phoenix'; // Required
            u.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US'; // Required
            u.EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1'; // Required
            u.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US'; // Required
            u.ProfileId = '<community-profile-id>';
```

Comment: Thanks!! My test class was screwed up because I was assigning Contact.Account = acct rather than Contact.AccountId = acct.Id.  It wasn't throwing an assignment error, but it was also never assigning an Account to the Contact.  Your code pointed me in the correct direction.  Big help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a useful guide to the options around user provisioning for communities
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/06/how-to-provision-salesforce-communities-users.html

You may also find the trailhead on external identity (Identity for customers) useful: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/identity_external